# C# IEnumerator with foreach loops, best design pattern?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, class-library, ienumerator

I know similar questions have been asked before, but I've come to a dead end while trying to find the best design pattern I can use.

I am trying to make a class-library with a factory class that provides enumerators for different items via method calls.
**Note**: Those items don't exist in a collection and can only be created knowing the previous one. (e.g. x(i) = x(i-1) + θ) Because of that I cannot implement those items as IEnumerable(s)

**What I thought until now**:

```
public static class AllItems {
    public sealed class ItemsEnumerator: IEnumerator<Item>{
       //those classes have non-public constructors
       .....
    }
    public static ItemsEnumerator GetItemsEnumerator() {
       return new ItemsEnumerator();
   }

    public sealed class OtherItemsEnumerator:IEnumerator<OtherItem>{
        ....
    }
    public static ItemsEnumerator GetOtherItemsEnumerator() {
       return new ItemsOtherEnumerator();
   }
}
```

this way i could do :

```
foreach(var item in AllItems.GetItemsEnumerator()){
   //do something with item
}
```

which won't work, because according to c# spec ItemsEnumerator doesn't have a GetEnumerator function(To be used in a foreach statement)

If I change it to this

```
public static class AllItems {
    public sealed class ItemsEnumerator: IEnumerator{
       .....
       public IEnumerator<Item> GetEnumerator() {
         return this;
       }
    }

    public static ItemsEnumerator GetItemsEnumerator() {
       return new ItemsEnumerator();
    } 
}
```

Is this a good design in general, or am I missing something here?

**EDIT**: Clarification on c# spec limitation

Comment: This question is a better candidate for CodeReview, which tends more to the theoretical and "big picture" thinking, whereas StackOverflow is more focused to very specific how-tos and fixes.

Comment: _"Because of that I cannot implement those items as IEnumerable(s)"_ -- I don't understand that statement. An `IEnumerable` implementation can return any sequence of values you want. If you can precisely describe the sequence (as one must, if one is to expect a computer to generate it), it can be returned via `IEnumerable`. Unfortunately, the tiny bit of code you provided is insufficient to clarify your apparent misunderstanding of the limitations of `IEnumerable` (or the lack thereof).

Comment: @B. Clay Shannon I thought about that, but I was wondering if this behavior would have side effects, and if there's a specific case where it will produce bad results?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon Code Review is actually about the *real, concrete, working code* - this question has way too much `do something` to fly on CR.

Comment: Still sounds like a job for the CodeReviewers to me.

Comment: add property type of your class to your class and you should get the idea. `class Item { public Item previousItem {get; set;}  }`

Comment: _"because according to c# spec ItemsEnumerator doesn't have a GetEnumerator function"_ -- I also don't understand this statement. `ItemsEnumerator` is your own class; the C# spec doesn't say one way or the other whether it should or does have `GetEnumerator()`. Furthermore, your example reads `AllItems.GetEnumerator()`, while according to the other part of the code example, it should read `AllItems.GetItemsEnumerator()` (which should work fine in `foreach`).

Comment: This question probably _is_ plausibly on-topic here, but only if you can do better with the presentation. Please provide a better code example, i.e. a good [mcve] that shows clearly what you're attempting to do, along with a _precise_ explanation of what that code does and how that's different from what you want it to do. A Stack Overflow question needs a clear problem statement, and so far I don't see one.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Well in order to have a class in a foreach statement it must provide a GetEnumerable function or Implement IEnumerable, right ?

Comment: @B.ClayShannon: Code Review is not for reviewing design patterns, they can be part of the review, however, Code Review is not about reviewing the walls, it's about reviewing the entire house. Simply a design pattern with hypothetical structures and content is not on-topic and would be closed fast on Code Review.

Comment: @GeorgeTG Your either or choice is the same thing, implementing `IEnumerable` makes your class provide a method named `GetEnumerator()`

Comment: `foreach` works for an object that has `GetEnumerator()`, implements `IEnumerable` or `IEnumerable<T>`, yes. So? How are you prevented from providing such an object? Why make `ItemsEnumerator` implement `IEnumerator` instead of `IEnumerable` if you want to be able to use it as the object of `foreach`? Alternatively, why not wrap it in an `IEnumerable` object that uses it, e.g. in an interator method or dedicated object?

Comment: @PeterDuniho I think I may have a problem understanding IEnumerable. The wrap solution seems close to what I may be looking for. So I should make a class e.g Items that provides a GetEnumerator method only or implements IEnumerable and the the code would be `var my_items = new Items(); foreach(var item in my_items) {}` right ?

Comment: Personally, I would just implement `ItemsEnumerable` instead of `ItemsEnumerator`. I don't see what the point of implementing `IEnumerator` instead of `IEnumerable` is. The latter is easier _and_ gives you more usage options. If you insist on implementing `ItemsEnumerator`, then I would just make the method `GetItemsEnumerable()` instead of `GetItemsEnumerator()`, and make that an iterator method (i.e. with `yield return`) that enumerates `ItemsEnumerator`.

Comment: Still, the question remains unclear to me: I'm not really comfortable saying exactly what is needed here; you seem to have constraints in mind that haven't been expressed clearly in the post. Without understanding those, I don't know how to answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am trying to make a class-library with a factory class that provides enumerators for different items via method calls. Note: Those items don't exist in a collection and can only be created knowing the previous one. (e.g. x(i) = x(i-1) + θ) Because of that I cannot implement those items as `IEnumerable(s)`

You don't need to go to that level of detail - you can just use `yield` to achieve a "conceptual" collection without having to wire in all of the enumeration plumbing:

```
public IEnumerable<Item> GetItems()
{
   int i = 0;
   while(i < 100) // or foreach(Item item in _baseItems), etc.
   {
       Item item = new Item();
       item.X = i;
       i += 10;
       yield return item;
   }
}
```

Note that this is *just for illustration* to show one way of returning a "collection" of items that are generated on-the fly.  You are free to adapt this to your situation in whatever way is appropriate.

Comment: Well that's an interesting way to do it, I don't know how I actually missed that in the reference.